# Paypal error: user is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: php, permissions, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to implement chained adaptive payment with the Paypal SOAP API. 
In my sandbox it works fine. Now I moved the code to the live API.
When I make a payment with a primary receiver it return this error:

> user is not allowed to perform this action

I have the application id and approval for my account. How can I solve this error?

Comment: the particular api's documentation should tell you what any particular error message means.

Comment: I think this is because of advanced permission is not enabled ? do you have any idea about how can i add permission for chained payment?

Comment: Nisam; www.x.com > Login > My account > New app > Submit a new application with the right permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are having this issue too, currently our app is only conditionally approved. The [top answer to this question on x.com](https://www.x.com/user/107130/feed) seems to suggest that some operations using the adaptive payments API, including chained payments (which we are having the issue with) won't work while the app is conditionally approved.

Quote from there for your convenience :)

> we were getting this error when "conditionally approved"
>   here is the answer from support
>
> Thank you for contacting Merchant Services.
>
> A transaction in "Conditionally Approved" status means that you will be able to process basic and parallel payments.
>
> Please note that it may take several days for our app review team to completely approve your application so that you can process chained payments.
>
> They should be in contact with you directly through x.com if they need more information before approving it.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same problem too, basic on [Paypal FAQ](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1633&expand=true&locale=en_US), we found the phase or state for getting a Live APP ID, there 2 phase there are:

**Request More Info Phase**

- Open indicates that your application has been received, is under review, and your AppID is not yet functional
- Conditionally Approved indicates that your application is still under review, but you have been granted basic functionality in the meantime.

**Final Decision Phase**

- **Auto-Approved** indicates that your account did not require a manual review and has automatically been approved. You now have full access. In most instances, basic requests (e.g., features and functionality) receive this action. Upon Auto-Approval, you are assigned a Live AppID and can begin Sandbox testing immediately.
- **Approved** indicates that your account has been manually reviewed and approved. You have been assigned a Live AppID and can begin working in the live production environment immediately.
- **Rejected** indicates that your application has been declined and your AppID has not been activated for functionality. You will receive an email explaining why your application was rejected and the same explanation will be accessible in your My Applications Dashboard. Your application is permanently closed after being rejected.
- **Retired** indicates that you manually opted in to deleting your application and, as a result, your AppID is no longer active.