# PayPal Adaptive Payments - User is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using paypal adaptive payments and i had sandbox account for this to be test for last 2 months it was working very much fine and all the transactions were successfully made by using sandbox.

Now what i'm trying to do is want to go live with adaptive payments get all the necessary information api id,password,signature, ap id etc. the problem is i'm facing right now is getting this error

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2014-12-08T21:53:30.943-08:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Failure
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => f8bdc47c42067
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 13414382
    [error(0).errorId] => 550001
    [error(0).domain] => PLATFORM
    [error(0).subdomain] => Application
    [error(0).severity] => Error
    [error(0).category] => Application
    [error(0).message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
    [error(0).parameter(0)] => Chained Payment
)
```

and i dont know where is the problem can you please help me out

Comment: You might want to look at this related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273236/paypal-error-user-is-not-allowed-to-perform-this-action

Comment: Yes i did look at the page but did not get the right answer i have app status that is "Approved Automatically", but what is the problem actually i am unable to locate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you Adaptive Payment application is not approved for **Chain Payments** and you are trying to execute Chain Payments API.

Go to `apps.paypal.com` and check(I can see that you are not enabled for chain Payments). In order to resolve the error, create a new application at apps.paypal.com and check "Chain Payments" and then use the new APP-ID to initiate this API call. It is also possible when your business/premier account is not **Verified**

**P.S** Btw, it is not possible to update the current application as it is already approved.So create new one.

Comment: Ya you are right now i have created app but that gives me the status that your app is conditionally approved. Should i wait for the app to approved by paypal automatically? or need to do something else\

Comment: You will just need to wait, the APP-review team will need to review and approve it. You can check your communications in apps.paypal.com